# How to trigger a gotfocus datagrid combobox event while grid is readonly?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox, eventhandler

I have a datagridview and I'm trying to get the gotfocus event for my comboboxcells to still call despite the datagrid being on readonly.

This gotfocus event changes the colour of every combobox with a similar value (including itself) and I would like to it to still call while on readonly (the datagridview comboboxes can still be selected/highlighted while on readonly but it is not called(?))

Below is the basics of how I am currently handling the events (for some reason this shortened version makes multiple event calls at an exponential rate & also requires three clicks to trigger... I'm not sure why it does this but my full project works fine in this regard)

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub cell_gotfocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    Dim CurrentCombo = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
    If Not CurrentCombo Is Nothing Then
        RemoveHandler CurrentCombo.GotFocus, AddressOf Combo_Focus 'remove event handler so we don't accumulate multiples

        AddHandler CurrentCombo.GotFocus, AddressOf Combo_Focus 'add eventhandler
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Combo_Focus()
    Console.WriteLine("Got Focus")
    Console.beep
End Sub

Private Sub Make_Readonly_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Make_Readonly.Click
    DataGridView1.Rows(0).ReadOnly = True 'toggle readonly
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For y As Integer = 1 To 4 'add extra columns into datagrid
        Dim cmb As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        cmb.HeaderText = "c" & DataGridView1.Columns.Count
        cmb.Name = "c" & DataGridView1.Columns.Count
        cmb.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb)
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I think EditingControlShowing only fires if you can edit the cell.  What happens if you try this code in `.CellEnter` event?

Comment: @JimmySmith Yes you are right. Do you know how I would go about declaring CurrentCombo as I no longer have access to e.Control? Although it will give me the row/col index of the combobox